# How to write to file outside working directory?

Tags: c++, file, fstream

I'm trying to figure out how to write to a file outside the working directory. This is the code I currently have.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string sp{};
    std::fstream ss("C:\\Users\\onion\\AppData\\Roaming\\MetaQuotes\\Terminal\\some numbers\\MQL5\\Files\\testnew.txt", std::ios::in | std::ios::out);
    if (!ss.is_open()) std::cout << "Failed" << '\n';
    else
    {
        while (ss.is_open())
        {
            std::getline(ss, sp);
            std::cout << sp << '\n';
            ss << "new data";
            if (ss.eof())break;
        }
    }
}
```

I can read the file perfectly fine, but I cant write to it? Could it be that Metatrader itself is limiting my ability to write to a file or does a file have to be in the working directory to be able to write to it? or am I just doing it wrong?

Comment: What does it do now? Does it just not write, or throw an error?

Comment: no error, just doesn't write.

Comment: What is the value of `ss.tellp()`?  Note that if another application has a write lock on the file, you might not be able to write but it's more likely that you simply won't be able to open it for write in the first place.  It sounds to me like this other app is actually overwriting the file repeatedly.  Try creating another file in that dir by copying this one and try the same thing.

Comment: the value is -1. okay I will try that :)

Comment: okay I can create and write to a file in that directory. I was trying to keep the number of files I would be working with to a minimum but this is fine. still, if you have any idea why this is happening it would be good to know :D and thanks for the new function! did not know about tellp()

Comment: Why are you opening the file for both read/write, writing to the file while you are reading from it? What is the goal here? Your loop looks suspiciously odd. For instance, `while (ss.is_open()) { std::getline(ss, sp); ... }` should be `while (std::getline(ss, sp)) { ... }` but then `if (ss.eof())` seems out of place.

Comment: originally it was intended to read the first line of the file and then write into that same file some output from an algorithm.  I see alot of people using the loop like that. if its not a good way to use it i will change it to your format.